# Blackberry 6: display menu on long click, run 1 action on short click

Tags: blackberry, menu, touch, gesture, tap

Hello fellow BB programmers,

if you look at the native Contacts (Addressbook) application on a Blackberry 6 phone with touch screen - it has a very natural behaviour:

1. On a short tap the default action is being executed - viewing the selected addressbook entry
2. On a long touch and hold a menu with several actions is displayed:

[image: Addressbook]

I'm trying to create an app with a ListField and similar (and intuitive) behaviour myself: **run default action on a short tap and display a menu in the middle of screen with several secondary actions on a longer touch**.

I've searched a lot and unfortunately only managed to create a test app with exactly opposite behaviour sofar:

I listen for a TouchGesture.HOVER and run editMenu.run(). And for the short tap a menu comes by itself (I haven't found yet, what makes it appear, some method in MainScreen/Screen?). I've tried running onMenu(0) but the menu appears in the top/right corner instead of screen center.

[image: MyList app]

Below is my very simple test code **MyList.java**, please help me to fix it:

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.*;
import net.rim.device.api.collection.*;
import net.rim.device.api.collection.util.*; 
import net.rim.device.api.system.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.*;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.decor.*;
import net.rim.device.api.util.*;

public class MyList extends UiApplication {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyList app = new MyList();
        app.enterEventDispatcher();
    }

    public MyList() {
        pushScreen(new MyScreen());
    }
} 

class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

    ObjectListField myList = new ObjectListField() {
        protected boolean touchEvent(TouchEvent event) {
            if (event.getEvent() == TouchEvent.GESTURE) {
                TouchGesture gesture = event.getGesture();
                if (gesture.getEvent() == TouchGesture.HOVER) {
                    System.err.println("XXX hover=" + gesture.getHoverCount() + ", index=" + myList.getSelectedIndex());
                    editMenu.run();
                    // onMenu(0);
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return super.touchEvent(event);
        }
    };

    private final MenuItem addMenu = new MenuItem("Add item", 0, 0) {  
        public void run() { 
            Status.show("Adding new item");
        }
    };

    private final MenuItem editMenu = new MenuItem("Edit item", 1, 0) {  
        public void run() { 
            Status.show("Editing existing item: " + myList.getSelectedIndex());
        }
    };

    private final MenuItem removeMenu = new MenuItem("Remove item", 2, 0) {  
        public void run() { 
            Status.show("Removing existing item: " + myList.getSelectedIndex());
        }
    };


    public MyScreen() {
        setTitle("How to display menu on long click?");
        myList.set(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", }); 
        add(myList);

        addMenuItem(addMenu);
        addMenuItem(editMenu);
        addMenuItem(removeMenu);
    }
}
```

Thank you!
Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue described here is related to the new [Pop-up menus](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/17971/Popup_menus_1133453_11.jsp) introduced in the OS 6. Using `TouchEvent` is a hack and will not work for all devices (not all OS 6 devices have a touch-screen).

```
class MyScreen extends MainScreen {

    ObjectListField myList = new ObjectListField() {
        protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
            editMenu.run();
            return true;
        }
    };

    private final MenuItem addMenu = new MenuItem("Add item", 0, 0) {  
        public void run() { 
            Status.show("Adding new item");
        }
    };

    private final MenuItem editMenu = new MenuItem("Edit item", 1, 0) {  
        public void run() { 
            Status.show("Editing existing item: " + myList.getSelectedIndex());
        }
    };

    private final MenuItem removeMenu = new MenuItem("Remove item", 2, 0) {  
        public void run() { 
            Status.show("Removing existing item: " + myList.getSelectedIndex());
        }
    };

    public MyScreen() {
        setTitle("How to display menu on long click?");
        myList.set(new String[] { "Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4", }); 
        add(myList);

        addMenuItem(addMenu);
        addMenuItem(editMenu);
        addMenuItem(removeMenu);
    }
}
```

Why this works as expected? Adding menu items to the screen implicitly sets a `ContextMenuProvider` for the screen (it defines a strategy for displaying a screen's pop-up menu). So the hover works as expected at a screen level - it is the screen who detects the "hover event" and opens the pop-up menu. On the other hand "taps" are handled with the list in `navigationClick()`.

Comment: I like the way you ask. So it's a pleasure to answer on such a well-stated question.